# Find maximum M which holds Inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Find maximum real number $M$, such that following inequality holds :

$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 3abc \geq M(ab+ bc + ca)  $$

for every positive real $a,b,c$ with $a+b+c=4$.

if $a=b=c=\frac{4}{3}$ than $M=\frac{7}{3}$. So I suspect that answer is $\frac{7}{3}$. However I wasn't able to prove it. If you can, please help me.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I missed to write it.

Comment: Please double check your calculations, for $a=b=c=\frac43 = x$, I get $3x^2+3x^3 \geqslant 3Mx^2 \implies M = \frac73$ would work.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it.

Answer (score 4):

Checking a few cases,
When $a=b=c=\frac43$, we have $7 \geqslant 3M \implies M \leqslant \frac73$.
When $a=b \to 2, c \to 0$ we get $8 \geqslant 4M \implies M \leqslant 2 < \frac73$.

So lets see if we can show (with $\sum$ denoting cyclic sums)
$$\sum a^2+3abc \geqslant 2\sum ab$$

Homogenising,
$$\iff \left(\sum a \right) \left(\sum a^2 \right) + 12 abc \geqslant 2\left( \sum a\right)\left(\sum ab \right)$$
$$\iff \sum a^3 + 6 abc \geqslant \sum ab(a+b)$$
which is true as the third degree Schur's inequality is $\sum a^3+3abc \geqslant \sum ab(a+b)$.

For equality to hold, we need two of the variables equal and the third to be zero, which is not in the domain, so there is no maximum $M$, only a supremum for $M$, which is $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for solution.